# Understanding Hibernate exception handling

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I have been reading about the advantages of using Hibernate over JDBC. One of the articles says

```
Hibernate wraps JDBC exceptions and throw an un-checked exception, so we don’t need to write code to handle it.
```

I am confused about where says "we don't need a code to handle it".
Isn't exception handling important to maintain the normal flow?

Comment: *Isn't exception handling important to maintain the normal flow* Yes, but let's imagine an `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown. There's no way to handle it in order to maintain the normal flow, just  with some code in a try block. Hibernate exceptions are `RuntimeExceptions`, which are, together with the `Errors`, unchecked . The text is telling there's no need to catch it because there's no way to recover from it, or/and is better to just let the VM handle it (most of the times, by finishing the thread)

Answer (score 0):

Good exception handling is important. But all it is saying that Hibernate is giving the user an option NOT to catch the exception (a la  RuntimeException). This can be useful for faster coding if you don't want to have to declare `throws JDBCException` through a long chain of method calls, or if you just want the exception to cause a fast fail (cannot proceed due to ...)

Comment: On the flip side, it allows you to completely ignore exception handling and write code that just crashes and quits, as opposed to handling the exception at the correct place and continuing gracefully.